# Problems with calculating the likelihood of an outcome based on cumulative probability function in R

Tags: r, probability-density

I am new to R and looking to estimate the likelihood of having an outcome>=100 using a probability density function (the outcome in my example is the size of an outbreak). I believe I have the correct coding, but something doesn't feel right about the answer, when I look at the plot.

This is my code (it's based on the output of a stochastic model of an outbreak). I'd very much appreciate pointers. I think the error is in the likelihood calculation....

Thank you!

```
total_cases.dist <- dlnorm(sample.range, mean = total_cases.mean, sd = total_cases.sd)
total_cases.df <- data.frame("total_cases" = sample.range, "Density" = total_cases.dist)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(total_cases.df, aes(x = total_cases, y = Density)) + geom_point()

pp <- function(x) {
  print(paste0(round(x * 100, 3), "%"))
}

# likelihood of n_cases >= 100
pp(sum(total_cases.df$Density[total_cases.df$total_cases >= 100]))
```

Comment: Can you provide the values you're using for `sample.range`, `total_cases.mean`, and `total_cases.sd`?

Comment: Thanks! sample.range <- 0:1000, total_cases.mean <- 1310.198, total_cases.sd <-31615.26

Answer (score 0):

You are using dlnorm, which is the log-normal distribution, which means the mean and sd are the mean of the log (values) and sd of log(values), for example:

```
# we call the standard rlnorm
X = rlnorm(1000,0,1)
# gives something close to sd = exp(1), and mean=something
c(mean(X),sd(X))
# gives what we simulated
c(mean(log(X)),sd(log(X)))
```

We now simulate some data, using a known poisson distribution where mean = variance. And we can model it using the log-normal:

```
set.seed(100)
X <- rpois(500,lambda=1310)
# we need to log values first
total_cases.mean <- mean(log(X))
total_cases.sd <- sd(log(X))
```

and you can see it works well

```
sample.range <- 1200:1400
hist(X,br=50,freq=FALSE)
lines(sample.range,
dlnorm(sample.range,mean=total_cases.mean,sd=total_cases.sd),
col="navyblue")
```

[image]

For your example, you can get probability of values > 1200 (see histogram):

```
plnorm(1200,total_cases.mean,total_cases.sd,lower.tail=FALSE)
```

Now for your data, if it is true that mean = 1310.198 and total_cases.sd = 31615.26, take makes variance ~ 76000X of your mean ! I am not sure then if the log normal distribution is appropriate for modeling this kind of data..

Comment: Yes, that coding (the latter) makes sense -- and I'll have to check the appropriateness of the distribution, as you say. Thanks again!